# Type 'String.CharacterView.IndexDistance' (aka 'Int') does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I am attempting to make a morse code converter in a Swift 3 playground. The function I am using does not successfully initiate the translation process, saying "Type 'String.CharacterView.IndexDistance' (aka 'Int') does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'".

```
func convertStringToMorse(_ input: String) -> String {
    let stringToConvert = input
    var charsInString = input.characters.count
    var returnString = ""
    for char in charsInString {
        let returnChar = convertLetterToMorse(char)
        if returnChar != "" {
            returnString += returnChar + " "
        }
    }
    return returnString
}
```

The error happens in the `for char in charsInString` line, specifically at `charsInString`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Delete `.count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the `.count`.

`input.characters.count` is an `Int` representing the number of characters.

`input.characters` represents the sequence of characters.

You can't use an `Int` in a `for-in` loop. You would need a collection or sequence.